# Slide Animation when switching to another scene in Godot Game Engine

Tags: user-experience, godot, gdscript

I'm making a GUI using godot and I want transition animation when switching to another scene instead of instant change (No animation) when using `get_tree().change_scene("MyOtherScene")`
I am trying to mimic the ios feel when switching to another scene. Is there any function to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? And if this does not work for you, please improve your question. https://godotengine.org/qa/3497/transitions-on-change-scene

Answer (score 0):

As i know both the function change_scene and change_scene_to cant be animated. But you can easily achieve the animation you need by using a common ancestor node and manage the transition there.
You can use an AnimationPlayer in both the transitioning scenes or a Tween node.